# PGFPlot rounding ticks on log scale

Tags: latex, tikz, pgfplots

when creating a pgfplot with a logarithmic scale, my x and y ticks get rounded once 1000 is passed, even with fixed precision settings. Is there an option I wasn't able to find in the manual that prevents this?

Thanks

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{%
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=1},
  }  
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    title={--},
    xlabel={--},
    ylabel={Median of Execution Time [ms]},
    xmin=0, xmax=4096,
    ymin=0, ymax=32375.5,
     log ticks with fixed point,
    xtick={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096},
    ytick={4,8,14,52,278,525,4524.5,14129.5,32375.5},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
    legend pos=north west,
    scaled ticks = false,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,3)(2,4)(4,4)(8,4)(16,4)(32,8)(64,14)(128,52)(256,278)(512,525)(1024,4524.5)(2048,14129.5)(4096,32375.5)
    };
    \legend{Execution Time}
    
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJv2S.png)

Comment: Please don't post code fragments

Comment: That's a good question for https://tex.stackexchange.com/ .